# Interquartile range from a step and leaf diagram

Tags: statistics

[image]

I'm told to find the interquartile range for these range of values presented in a step and leaf diagram , however , I only know how to find values of upper quartile , lower quartile through a cumulative frequency graph , is there any methods to find the upper quartile and lower quartile for values that I presented in a step and leaf diagram / Dot diagram / etc ?

Thanks in advance !

Is the answer 10?

Comment: The Wikipedia page on quartiles (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile) might be helpful. They list 3 different methods for computing quartiles. If you have a textbook, I would recommend referencing their definition/method of computation to see which one you should use.

Comment: Hint: convert the step and leaf diagram to a list of numbers.